# Excel with Blank cells and a IF/AND statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cells A1-A7 with A1 needing the formula. Cells A2-A7 have dropdown list options of "Y" or "N". What I'm needing is for A1 to remain blank until a "Y/N" option is chosen for cells A2-A7. Once A2-A7 have data (Y or N) I need them to be evaluated so that if there is a "N" in any cell of A2-A7, then A1 will display "N". If no "N" is input in A2-A7, then A1 will display "Y"

The formula I'm currently using in cell A1 is:

`=IF(COUNTBLANK(M3:M7)>0,"",(IF(AND(M3="N",M4="N",M5="N",M6="N",M7="N"),"N","Y")))`

This formula is keeping the A1 cell blank no matter what is input into A2-A7. Any ideas?

Comment: You mention A2-A7 but the formula is for M3-M7. Also that should be an `OR` not an `AND`

Comment: Sorry, I was generalizing in the question. The cells that I am using in my spreadsheet are M2:M7 with M2 needing he formula.

Comment: Changing AND to OR did not fix the problem. The formula cell remains blank when a Y or N is input into the cells.

Comment: Are all the cells m3:m7 filled out? The AND/OR would only fix the desired outcome you have specified in the body, the blank issue is probably the outer IF testing for blank cells.

Comment: If they are left blank than the formula cell remains blank. If they are populated with a Y or an N, then the formula cell remains blank using either the AND or OR. Removing the outer IF makes the formula invalid.

Comment: Then I can't repro this, it works for me.

Comment: pull your formula apart.  Put `=COUNTBLANK(M3:M7)` in another cell and see if it returns what you expect it to.

Comment: Then if that is producing results that you think are incorrect, put `=isblank(M3)` in an empty column and copy down to see which one(s) are giving the incorrect data.

Comment: Also you say you have dropdown lists, are those Data Validation lists or are the form or activex controls?

Comment: From Data Validation lists

Comment: And the results of putting the `ISBLANK()` formulas in an empty column, do they match what you would expect?

Comment: Before adding the COUNTBLANK part the IF/AND statement worked as wanted. I added the COUNTBANK so that the formula cell would remain blank until data was chosen for the other cells. Otherwise it populated with a Y.

Comment: Personally I would use a formula using countif: `=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A7,""),"",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A7,"N")>=1,"N","Y"))`

Comment: I've got it now. I was not populating the entire range for the COUNTBLANK to go to false.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this, but the one first coming to mind for me is to rewrite the second part of your formula.

Keep this part, to check if you have all of your cells filled out

```
IF(COUNTBLANK(M3:M7)>0,"",
```

Then, I'd use the same method for finding out if any of the cells hold the value "N"

```
IF(COUNTIF(M3:M7,"N")>0;"N";"Y")
```

This is a personal choice, but I find reading the code is easier if you use versions of the same function like this.

The whole code would then be

```
IF(COUNTBLANK(M3:M7)>0,"",IF(COUNTIF(M3:M7,"N")>0,"N","Y"))
```

PS: I saw in the comment someone suggested splitting the original formula up in different cells to figure out where it goes wrong. There's also a built-in function that allows you to calculate a formula step-by-step and see the results. It's called Evaluate Formula and can be found under the Formula section.